# I have encountered a strange problem when i want to compile a linux driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

```
make -C /home/doney/100ask_imx6ull_mini-sdk/Linux-4.9.88 M=`pwd` modules 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/doney/100ask_imx6ull_mini-sdk/Linux-4.9.88'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
FATAL: section header offset=11259037725229108 in file 'vmlinux' is bigger than filesize=20304380
scripts/Makefile.modpost:91: recipe for target '__modpost' failed
make[2]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
Makefile:1502: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/doney/100ask_imx6ull_mini-sdk/Linux-4.9.88'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried to clean `make clean` and `make dtbs`

Comment: A) What compiler version? B) What architecture? C) What driver?

Comment: Are you trying to cross-compile the driver? Perhaps you need to pass values for `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` on the `make` command line.